# Moving one turtle to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am writing a program that requires one turtle to move to another. However the simple:

```
turtle.goto(other_turtle.pos())
```

where turtle and other_turtle are two already defined turtles

That does not work because it says that `other_turtle.pos()` is a method and subtraction between a method and floats is not defined. So then I continued to try and change the `other_turtle.pos()` to `float(other_turtle.pos())`. Then that errored out saying that you can't float a method.

My question: Is this possible to do this or due to the limitations of the python turtle itself impossible?

code:

```
def turtle_clone(clone_nmb):
    return [turtle.Turtle() for i in range(clone_nmb)]

def straight_curve(turtle,number_of_arms,number_of_points,colors):
    turtles = turtle_clone(2)
    turtles[0].hideturtle()
    turtles[1].hideturtle()
    turtles[0].color(colors[0])
    turtles[1].color(colors[0])
    pos = 0
    for i in range(number_of_arms):
        turtles[0].setheading(pos)
        turtles[0].forward(5)
        turtles[1].setheading(pos+(360/number_of_arms))
        turtles[1].forward(5*number_of_points)
        turtles[1].right(180)
        for i in range(number_of_points):
            turtles[0]
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(turtles[0].xcor,turtles[0].ycor)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(turtles[1].xcor,turtles[1].ycor)
            turtles[0].forward(5)
            turtles[1].forward(5)
        pos += 360/number_of_arms
        turtles[0].goto(0,0)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gularson\Documents\Garrett\Messing Around\turtle_functions.py", line 97, in <module>
    straight_curve(turt,5,30,["white"])
  File "C:\Users\gularson\Documents\Garrett\Messing Around\turtle_functions.py", line 87, in straight_curve
    turtle.goto(turtles[0].xcor,turtles[0].ycor)
  File "C:\Users\gularson\Documents\Garrett\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 1776, in goto
    self._goto(Vec2D(x, y))
  File "C:\Users\gularson\Documents\Garrett\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 3165, in _goto
    diff = (end-start)
  File "C:\Users\gularson\Documents\Garrett\Python\lib\turtle.py", line 262, in __sub__
    return Vec2D(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'method' and 'float'
```

Comment: always put in question FULL error message (Traceback) - it can be more usefull than your description.

Comment: are you sure you use `()` in `pos()` ? From your description it looks like you use `turtle.goto(other_turtle.pos)` without `()`. Better show full error message and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression:

```
turtle.goto(other_turtle.pos())
```

does work.  The following runs without error:

```
import turtle

other_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

turtle.goto(other_turtle.pos())

turtle.done()
```

But of course, it isn't very interesting (moves a turtle at (0, 0) atop the other turtle already at (0, 0), but it's legal.)  So there must be something else tripping you up.

What you actually wrote in your code is:

```
turtle.goto(other_turtle.xcor, other_turtle.ycor)

turtle.goto(turtles[0].xcor,turtles[0].ycor)
```

which will cause the error you reported as you're passing the methods `xcor` and `ycor` instead of calling them.  It should have been:

```
turtle.goto(other_turtle.xcor(), other_turtle.ycor())

turtle.goto(turtles[0].xcor(), turtles[0].ycor())
```

or the original code you asked about:

```
turtle.goto(other_turtle.pos())

turtle.goto(turtles[0].pos())
```

would have worked fine.

Comment: I defined the turtle that is moving with a name, the given input, but the one it is moving to doesn't have a name and was defined in a list.

Comment: @GarrettGularson, I've updated my answer now that there's sufficient context to see the error in your code.